# Problem with matrix product definition inside class

Tags: python, arrays, class, matrix

I'm trying to make a basic matrix class without numpy. Every operation works just fine, except for the matrix multiplication. I can't see what exactly is wrong with it. Any ideas?

```
import cmath
i  = cmath.sqrt(-1)

class Matrix:
    def __init__(self, Data):
        self.Data = Data
    
    def __add__(self, OpMat):
        Data = []
        for i in range(len(self.Data)):
            Data.append([])
            for j in range(len(self.Data[0])):
                Data[i].append(self.Data[i][j] + OpMat.Data[i][j])
        return Matrix(Data)

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.Data)

    def MatrixMul(self, OpMat):
        Data = []
        for i in range(len(self.Data)):
            Data.append([])
            for j in range(len(OpMat.Data[0])):
                Sum = 0
                for k in range(len(self.Data[0])):
                        Sum += Data[i].append(self.Data[i][j]*OpMat.Data[j][i])
        return Matrix(Data)
  
# Example
x = Matrix([[1,2,3 + 2*i],[2,3,4],[2,3,4]])
y = Matrix([[10,10,10],[10,10 + i, 10],[10,10,10]])


print(x.MatrixMul(y))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of problems. I will point out where and you take it from there

```
def MatrixMul(self, OpMat):
    Data = []
    for i in range(len(self.Data)):
        Data.append([])
        for j in range(len(OpMat.Data[0])):
            Sum = 0
            Data[i].append([])
            for k in range(len(self.Data[0])):
                Sum += self.Data[i][j]*OpMat.Data[j][i]
            Data[i, j] = Sum
    return Matrix(Data)
```

The append statement in the loop is the problem. Not sure all is ok. Take it from there.

Comment: I tried to use this by changing Data[i, j] to just Data[i][j] and the output made sense. However, the result is not correct. If i make a matrix x = [[1,2,3][7,8,9]] and y = [[1,2][7,8][13,14]], the output should be [[54,60],[180,204]] instead of [[3, 42],[42,192]]. I will take a look anyway, thanks!